# Серверное решение

Tags: drupal, php, java

Доброго времени суток!

у меня есть приложение под Андроид, являющееся каталогом песен для караоке, и задумал я расширить функционал, серверной частью.

Какие задачи:
Идентификация клиентов
получение записи с клиента
отображение записей
разграничение прав доступа к листу с записями
возможность менять порядок записей
Логика работы, человек находит песню в приложении, нажимает заказать, отправляется запрос на сервер, песня попадает в список.

вот сижу думаю на чем лучше реализовать, обычно я использую Друпал, но для этой задачи как то мне кажется его не совсем логично использовать. Хотя конечного можно органикгруп+вес ноды + какой то самописный API модуль. Минус, при повторном заказе песен ноды будут дублироваться, короче мне кажется это какой то совсем не дзен путь.

чистый php, как бы писать много, API, админка...

Может кто решал подобную задачу, какие есть красивые решения, что выбрать для реализации серверной части?

может на Java есть какие то фреймворки которые позволяют это реализовать красиво и быстро?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Roo но нужно хорошо разбираться и понимать как работает Spring*, Hibernate ну и знать Core Java. По пэхэпе ничего сказать не могу так как не пишу на нем. Можно достаточно быстро написать на Python с Tornado.

Comment: хмм... интересная штука это Spring Roo интересные подсказки, так же нашел что можно и GWT юзать. Спасибо.